# Where clause not enforced

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I use laravel eloquent outside laravel.
I have a query that is supposed to get only posts that are featured (featured field = 1) and of any of the 3 types (blog, forum and page).

```
    $latestFeaturedPosts = $db->table( 'posts' )
                              ->where( 'featured', '=', 1 )
                              ->orWhere( 'post_type', '=', 'blog' )
                              ->orWhere( 'post_type', '=', 'forum' )
                              ->orWhere( 'post_type', '=', 'page' )
                              ->limit( 15 )
                              ->orderBy( 'created_at', 'desc' )
                              ->get()->toArray();
```

I expected this query to return what I wanted, but it does return also posts where `featured`column is not 1.
Why ? How should I modify this syntax to enforce this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for you:

```
$db->table('posts')
    ->where('featured', 1)
    ->whereIn('post_type', ['blog', 'forum', 'page'])
    ->limit(15)
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->get()->toArray();
```

Your query doesn't work as expected because you're using `orWhere()` without a closure which would group `orWhere()` clauses.

Answer (score 1):

I do not now this language, but will give you a starting point to look into.

Your query will be expanded to:

```
SELECT * FROM posts where featured = 1 OR post_type = 'blog' OR post_type = 'forum' OR post_type = 'page' LIMIT 15 ORDER BY created_at DESC;
```

In this query, any row that matches any one of the 4 criteria will be returned.

For you to get the results you expect, your query needs to be evaluated to:

```
SELECT * FROM posts where featured = 1 AND ( post_type = 'blog' OR post_type = 'forum' OR post_type = 'page' ) LIMIT 15 ORDER BY created_at DESC;
```

In this example, we will always enforce the featured type, and then can select any 3 types that are also featured.

How to do this in your language, I am not sure.